# Submultiplicative function vs regular variation function

Tags: real-analysis

Let us define the following two function class:  A submultiplicative function is defined by $f(xy)\leq f(x)f(y), x,y\geq 0$ refer paper [1989(Gustavasson)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250752673_A_submultiplicative_function). A regular variation function is defined by $g(\lambda x)/g(x)\to \lambda^\alpha, x,\lambda\geq 0$ refer book [2013(Bingham)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/regular-variation/A71D6C4A65CFC1806E1DB7109128A358).
As we can see that, if $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$, we can get $f(x)=x^\beta$ and this kind of fuinction is regular variation. Can we claim that: A submultiplicative function is regular variation function?
Is there someone can give me some trick or some reference to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(t)=t^p(1+|\sin(\log(t)|)$, $p\ge1$ is submultiplicative, but it is not of regular variation (see e.g., Example 5 in Maligranda L. Indices and interpolation. Dissertationes Mathematicae. 1985; 234:1–54).